# Node module missing error when script tries to restart

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, node-modules, forever

I am running `CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)` and I frequently run into a problem of missing node modules.

Here are some paths I printed on the console:

```
which npm
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.2.1/bin/npm

which node
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.2.1/bin/node

which forever
/usr/local/bin/forever
```

Now, when I start the script with forever it runs. Sometimes in the midnight, when I just verify if all the scripts are running, many are failing and the error is something like:

[image]

I have to go and install the node module. What could possibly be the reason for this? Could it be some permission issue?

Comment: @TGrif What are ghost packages?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you have `fs-extra` installed at the directory you working or globally (if not - just run `npm install fs-extra`)
2. If you are going to work with AWS.S3 - check credentials permissions (for example `aws s3 ls` - you should see list of available buckets)